# What's the result of passing just nil to arrayWithArray:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarray

What happens when you pass `nil` to `arrayWithArray:`?

Let's say I have the following code:

`NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:someOtherArray];`

If `someOtherArray` happens to be `nil`, will `myArray` be `nil` or will it be an empty mutable array?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Just as @JacquesCousteau asked : `NSLog(@"%@", [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nil]);`

Comment: It would be quite unexpected if a new array was *not* returned...

Comment: @JacquesCousteau I did not try it, hence the reason I said I was looking for a quick answer.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau I was doing a code review via Crucible and did not have my development environment setup and the API docs did not provide the information I was looking for. Normally I would not ask such a simple question but I was in need of a quick answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An empty array is returned.

An example implementation of `+arrayWithArray:` would be the following:

```
+(id) arrayWithArray:(NSArray *) arr
{
    NSMutableArray *returnValue = [NSMutableArray new];
    returnValue->objectsCount = [arr count];
    returnValue->objectsPtr = malloc(sizeof(id) * returnValue->objectsCount);
    [arr getObjects:returnValue->objectsPtr range:NSMakeRange(0, returnValue->objectsCount)];
    return returnValue;
}
```

Thus, if `arr` is null, `-count` returns 0, nothing is `malloc`'d, and nothing is copied, because a message sent to a nil object returns the default return value for that type, and does nothing else.

Comment: I was expecting nil instead of an empty array. I'm sure the docs explain it, but I just assumed. Good I decided to check before pulling my hair!

Comment: You should no longer count on this, since the method parameter is implicitly nonnull. The static analyzer will warn you about this now.